# How do I run a Spring Boot application from the applications root directory?

Tags: spring, maven, cmd

I'm not too sure how to best present my issue but I'll try my best.
I have made a spring boot application in Eclipse but when I go to the command prompt and enter where the application is(it's directory) and type the following line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I get the following error:
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In eclipse I right clicked over the application and did runs as -> maven Install. 
Then I tried to right click over the application.java file and go run as -> but the option for "spring boot app" is not there?

I'm just trying to start Spring Boots default tomcat port.

Comment: It looks like you don't have Maven installed for command line use; maybe start by fixing that?

Comment: From eclipse, right click on your project and try the option **run as > maven build...** with the goal `spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't add mavan bin to PATH variable 
Please refer
https://maven.apache.org/install.html

If you want to build it from eclipse .Just right click and maven package/install it will make jar in target folder in root folder .Go to the target folder and do

```
java -jar jarname.jar
```